# Tag merge: 'bsod' and 'bluescreen'

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[bluescreen](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bluescreen) and [bsod](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bsod) are duplicates as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

This has been completed [bluescreen](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bluescreen) was synonymed to [bsod](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bsod).